# Why does this work, finding min value and index for an array

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

This program takes user input 10 times, then determines the lowest value and the index location for that lowest value.

Why does this if-statement work? The "counter == 0" part, wouldn't that always be false? Meaning the code wouldn't work? Yet it does?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#define arraySize 10

int getNum(void);

int main()
{
    int myArray[arraySize] = {0};
    int counter = 0;
    
    int minIndex = 0;
    int minValue = 0;
    
    printf("Enter 10 Integer Values\n");
    
    for (counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        printf("Enter Integer #%d: ", counter);
        myArray[counter] = getNum();
        
        
        if (counter == 0 || (minValue > myArray[counter]))
        {
            minValue = myArray[counter];
            minIndex = counter;
        }
        
    }
    
    printf("Min: %d, Index: %d.", minValue, minIndex);
    
    return 0;
}



int getNum(void)
{
char record[121] = {0};
int number = 0;
    fgets(record, 121, stdin);
    if( sscanf(record, "%d", &number) != 1 )
    {
        number = -1;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: The initial value of the variable counter is 0. So the if statement will be executed in any case in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: First of all, `counter` can be 0 (it is, upon the first iteration). Second, it's an `||` expression, meaning that even when `counter` is not 0, it can still be true.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow For the second iteration, wouldn't counter then become 1? Or would counter always remain at 0

Comment: @Joey What do you think `counter++` does?

Comment: What do you think "the second iteration" means?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how `for` loops work.

Comment: @goodvibration I think it means the loop is then executed again (second time)

Comment: @Joey For all other iterations of the loop except the first the sub-expression counter == 0 will evaluates to false. So the second sub-expression (minValue > myArray[counter]) will be checked whether it is true or false.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I believe I understand now, in your opinion could this have been written better?

Comment: @Joey Yes it could be written better. For example the variable minValue is redundant. it is enough to have the index of the minimal element of the array.

Comment: One option is to change to `if (myArray[minIndex] >= myArray[counter]) { minIndex = counter; }`

Answer (score 0):

Lets work with this inputs:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1

In the first iteration `counter==0` is true and `minValue > myArray[counter]` is false because 0 > 0 return false, the operator || allow to enter the if.

In the following iterations the sentence `counter==0` will be false ever, but the `minValue > myArray[counter]` will be false or true depends on the number.
With 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 will be false but whit -1 will enter because 0 > -1.
And make the min value = -1;

The || operator works like this:

```
true || true =true
true || false =true
false || true ==true
false || false ==false
```

To sum up, if there is one true sentence the program will enter in the if sentence.